# Can I make my own p-trap

Tags: plumbing, shower, p-trap

I am doing some plumbing in a country where p-traps for showers are not readily available. The local option is not viable for me, and ordering p-traps online would take some time. Is there any reason you can think of that I couldn't make my own trap out of some 90 degree elbows provided I follow the 2" min, 4" max guidelines on trap wier depths?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't know what country you're in but from a physics perspective you could certainly do it. You seem to know the basics about the depth of the weir. The other things you need to consider is to avoid building an S trap. The tail from the P trap needs to come off of it horizontally with a 1/4" per foot slope to the drain and note the max lengths of pipe below. Sounds as if you've got it.

[image]